# Would training a BERT Multi-Label Classifier for 100 labels decrease accuracy a lot?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, text-classification

I am trying to train a text classifier which would be able to classify a sentence as being of a certain query type. I have used the BERT Model and trained a Multi-Label classifier which does the job with 90% accuracy for about 20 labels.
My question is that if I have to train the model for 100/200 labels would the accuracy be impacted severely?

Answer (score 1):

If your class distributions does not have a large overlap and you have the good amount of train data representing each class, your accuracy should not be severely impacted. For data hungry model like BERT its all about data. If you have large amount of data represent your 100/200 class you are good to go.